# Alpha-Beta Pruning and Depth skews checkmate evaluation

Tags: engines, programming

I am currently working on a chess engine in golang. I have implemented and tested move generation, making and unmaking. I am working on search and evaluation using Negamax with Alpha Beta pruning, this is the code I have:

```
func Negamax(alpha, beta eval.Relative, depth int) {
    originalAlpha := alpha

    // check for transposition table hits

    if entry, hit := c.ttable[c.board.Hash]; hit && entry.depth >= depth {
        c.tthits++

        switch entry.eType {
        case exact:
            return entry.value
        case lowerBound:
            alpha = max(alpha, entry.value)
        case upperBound:
            beta = min(beta, entry.value)
        }

        if alpha >= beta {
            return entry.value
        }
    }

    // depth == 0 or terminal nodes: evaluate current position

    if c.board.IsInCheck(c.board.SideToMove.Other()) {
        return eval.Infinity // king is captured
    }

    if depth == 0 
        return eval.Of(c.board)
    }

    // search moves

    moves := c.board.GenerateMoves()
    score := eval.Relative(-evaluation.Infinity)
    for _, m := range moves {
        c.board.MakeMove(m)
        curr := -c.Negamax(-beta, -alpha, depth-1)
        c.board.Unmove(m)

        // propagate checkmate
        switch {
        case curr > evaluation.WinInMaxPly:
            curr--
        case curr < evaluation.LoseInMaxPly:
            curr++
        }

        score = max(score, curr)
        alpha = max(alpha, score)

        if alpha >= beta {
            break
        }
    }

    // check for mate

    if score == -evaluation.Mate && !c.board.IsInCheck(c.board.SideToMove) {
        score = evaluation.Draw // stalemate
    }

    // update transposition table
    c.ttable[c.board.Hash] = ttEntry{
        value: score,
        depth: depth,
        eType: entryType(score, originalAlpha, beta),
    }

    return score
```

Here are the definitions of some of the constants:

```
const (
    Infinity = 1073741823
    Mate = Infinity - 1
    Draw = 0

    WinInMaxPly = Mate - 2*1000
    LoseInMaxPly = -WinInMaxPly
)
```

I calculate the number of plys till mate using `WinInMaxPly - score`.

Using the above mentioned code, with `alpha = -1073741823`, `beta = 1073741816` and `depth = 11`, the position `fen(8/8/8/8/3K4/2Q5/3p4/3k4 w - - 24 13)` is evaluated as `#4(8 plys)` instead of `#3(6 plys)`. The proper evaluation is given if `depth >= 12` which is confusing since the mate is in 6 plays, not 12.

I have properly tested the move making and unmaking functions, and the psudo legal move generator.

The particular value of alpha and beta were used because the error was first detected in the position `fen(8/8/8/8/3K4/2Q5/2kp4/8 b - - 23 12)` on which the move `c2d1` transposes to the given position. The call to negamax in this original position used the given values of alpha and beta.